# Cognos 11 Query join problems

Tags: join, report

I have a report with 8 different queries. Then we get the error message XQE-PLN-0223 The query uses the join 'Query1' between entities 'Person_HR' and 'PAID IN 2023'. This join is unacceptable since its expression does not reference the entities of the join.

I have tried looking at Join Relations in the properties as well as filter types. I can alter the error message by deleting the join. Both of the data items are text items in the SQL database so at least they are configured the same.